# converting multiple rows into multiple columns in mysql

Tags: mysql-workbench

I have a mysql database of 10 records rows and 2 columns.

I want to split data into 6 columns (3 record rows of 2 columns each) then loop the next (3 record rows of 2 columns each), and so on until the end.

My input data is :

```
---COUNTRY---CAPITAL 
---FRANCE---PARIS  
---GERMANY---BERLIN  
---ITALY---ROME  
---SWITZERLAND---BERN  
---NETHERLANDS---AMSTERDAM  
---GREECE---ATHENS  
---NORWAY---OSLO  
---SWEDEN---STOCKHOLM  
---FINLAND---HELSINKI  
---DENMARK---COPENHAGEN
```

OUTPUT DESIRED :

```
---COUNTRY1---CAPITAL1---COUNTRY2---CAPITAL2---COUNTRY3---CAPITAL3
---FRANCE---PARIS---SWITZERLAND---BERN---NORWAY---OSLO  
---GERMANY---BERLIN---NETHERLANDS---AMSTERDAM---SWEDEN---STOCKHOLM  
---ITALY---ROME---GREECE---ATHENS---FINLAND---HELSINKI  
---DENMARK---COPENHAGEN
```

Comment: Your data seems poorly formatted. Please format it so we can better understand your problem. Plus it would be helpful if you provided your db scheme.

Comment: Dear Shinar, Thanks for quick response, I am really new to mysql. I have tried to format it as best as possible. please let me know if its ok.

Comment: Formatting is much better now. You said there should be 5 columns but in your data it shows only 2. Should I assume each row contains rows where the number has the same last digit?

Comment: not exactly but it is divisible by 10